# Access JSON values from URL

Tags: c#, php, json, windows-8

I am trying to get data from a URL that contains JSON values. These values are to be used in my windows 8 desktop app. The code I have tried is seen below.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(App.DataServiceUrl + "/productcategory");
var Groups = new List<GroupList>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var prods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
    foreach (var data in prods)
    {
        var dataGroup = new GroupList
              (
                 data.term_id,
                  data.name,
                 data.slug,
                   data.description,
                  data.taxonomy
              );
        Groups.Add(dataGroup);

    }
}
```

The URL I am accessing is actually a page in a website where I call some fucntions to get some data in php and then use `json_encode($all);` to return json data. When I access the url, I can see all the JSON data.

One example of the data from URL is:

```
[{"term_id":"64","name":"Argentina","slug":"argentina","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"64","taxonomy":"product_cat","description":"","parent":"13","count":"20","meta_id":"154","woocommerce_term_id":"64","meta_key":"order","meta_value":"0","cat_ID":"64","category_count":"20","category_description":"","cat_name":"Argentina","category_nicename":"argentina","category_parent":"13"},...]
```

But the application doesn't recognize the json values when I try to access them such as term_id, name etc. (as seen in code above)

Instead when I run the application I get this error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path", line 4, position 2

How do I  get and use the values from the url in my C# code?

Comment: "URL I am accessing is actually a page" - does it mean that GET for that URL returns text/html and not JSON? Please clarify. Clearly if you trying to parse HTML as JSON you'll get error very similar to one mentioned in the post "Unexpected character `<` " .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is the page :http://cbbnideas.com/brydens-website/api/, it is a wordpress website page where I simply echo the data via json_encode.

Comment: No, you are doing something else too (posted as answer as need to have formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page produces some random text in front of JSON. You can take any HTTP debugger (my favorite is Fiddler, but anything would do) to confirm. Here are first several lines of the response from `http://cbbnideas.com/brydens-website/api/` - note that JSON starts at 8th line:

```
37



 <!--All Categories (And Sub Categories)-->

6bd8
[{"term_id":"64","name":"Argentina","slug":"argentina","term_gr...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DynamicJson](http://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/) class to parse the JSON, as far as I know it's the best option.